# Invoke inherited member functions using $this->my_func() or parent::my_func()?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, inheritance

I've been creating abstract classes and interfaces to force consistency within my Wordpress plugins, but I'm never sure if I should be invoking inherited functions by using parent::some_function() or using $this->some_function()?  Since jumping back and forth between the two looks super messy/confusing.

For Example:
Using getter/setters should I be:

```
$this->get_my_var(); // indicating nothing about its origins except through comments
```

or

```
parent::get_my_var(); // indicating you can find it in the parent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not the same thing.

```
class A {
    protected function foo() {
        return "a";
    }
}
class B extends A {
    protected function foo() {
        return parent::foo() . "b";
    }
    public function bar() {
        return $this->foo();
    }
}

$b = new B();
var_dump($b->bar()); // "ab"
```

If instead you had:

```
class B extends A {
    ...
    public function bar() {
        return parent::foo();
    }
}

var_dump($b->bar()); // just "a"
```

The `foo` function of `B` adds something to the `foo` function of `A`. This is a common pattern.

Whether calling `parent::foo` in `bar` is good or not depends on your design choices, I personally think it's a little iffy. Calling `parent::foo` in `foo` is fine by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I only use `parent::` in constructors, destructors and static methods. For everything else I trust people to know how object inheritance works. I would use `$this->get_my_var();`